# Random Forest Feature Importance using Python

Tags: python, random-forest, nameerror

I am trying the below code for random forest classifier. Even though I have defined but getting NameError.
Please help

```
def RFC_model(randomState, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):


   rand_forest = RandomForestClassifier()
   rand_forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
   forest_test_predictions = rand_forest.predict(X_test)
   print(accuracy_score(y_test, forest_test_predictions))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_encoded.drop(['success'],axis='columns').values,      
                                                df_encoded.success, 
                                                test_size=0.2)

RFC_model(42, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)

0.994045375744328

rand_forest.feature_importances_.round(3)

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-974786899b7f> in <module>
  1 #importance of features rounded to nearest 3 decimals
----> 2 rand_forest.feature_importances_.round(3)

NameError: name 'rand_forest' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the variable `rand_forest` locally in the scope of the `RFC_model` function. Once the function finishes executing, the object is destroyed, so you cannot access it. You can solve this by returning the `rand_forest` object:

```
def RFC_model(randomState, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
    rand_forest = RandomForestClassifier()
    rand_forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
    forest_test_predictions = rand_forest.predict(X_test)
    print(accuracy_score(y_test, forest_test_predictions))
    return rand_forest

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_encoded.drop(['success'],axis='columns').values,      
                                            df_encoded.success, 
                                            test_size=0.2)

rand_forest = RFC_model(42, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
rand_forest.feature_importances_.round(3)
```